# How to get the last character of a string in a shell?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have written the following lines to get the last character of a string:

```
str=$1
i=$((${#str}-1))
echo ${str:$i:1}
```

It works for `abcd/`:

```
$ bash last_ch.sh abcd/
/
```

It **does not work for `abcd*`**:

```
$ bash last_ch.sh abcd*
array.sh assign.sh date.sh dict.sh full_path.sh last_ch.sh
```

It **lists the files in the current folder**.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

That's one of the reasons why you need to quote your variables:

```
echo "${str:$i:1}"
```

Otherwise, bash expands the variable and in this case does globbing before printing out. It is also better to quote the parameter to the script (in case you have a matching filename):

```
sh lash_ch.sh 'abcde*'
```

Also see the order of expansions in the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions). Variables are expanded before the filename expansion.

To get the last character you should just use `-1` as the index since the negative indices count from the end of the string:

```
echo "${str: -1}"
```

**The space after the colon (`:`) is REQUIRED.**

This approach will not work without the space.

Comment: BTW, negative indices count from right, so `"${1: -1}"` is enough.

Comment: You should reply as formal solution, not here in comments.

Comment: FYI: you can also do this in a "one-liner" as `echo "${str:$((${#str}-1)):1}"`.  This allows you to vary the trailing characters returned as well. This work for me in bash v4.1.0(1)

Comment: @choroba's answer: Note the damn space! This always trips me up: `"${1:-1}` does not work"!

Answer (score 259):

Per @perreal, quoting variables is important, but because I read this post like five times before finding a simpler approach to the question at hand in the comments...

```
str='abcd/'
echo "${str: -1}"
=> /
```

Alternatively use `${str:0-1}` as pointed out in the comments.

```
str='abcd*'
echo "${str:0-1}"
=> *
```

**Note**: The extra space in `${str: -1}` is **necessary**, otherwise `${str:-1}` would result in `1` being taken as the default value if `str` is null or empty.

```
${parameter:-word}
       Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the
       expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of
       parameter is substituted.
```

Thanks to everyone who participated in the above; I've appropriately added +1's throughout the thread!

Comment: NB: note the space inside `${std: -1}`, without the space this won't work. I ran into this and found that `${std:~0}` also works (with or without space). Not sure if this is documented behavior though, I haven't bothered to look it up.

Comment: it is documented.
man bash says:
Arithmetic expressions starting with a - must be separated by whitespace from the preceding : to be distinguished from the Use Default Values expansion

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for sharing. The BASH manpage is almost overwhelming to read though, I've been in there several times. I think they could make a college course around shell scripting lol.

Comment: This solution does not work in an `.sh` script when trying to assign the retrieved character to a variable.  For instance `declare LAST=$(echo "${str: -1}")`

This will result in the nasty red bar showing a syntax error starting at the :

Comment: if editor syntax checking does not like that space try `${str:0-1}`

Comment: Alternative syntax to `${str: -1}` is `${str::-1}`.

Answer (score 60):

I know this is a very old thread, but no one mentioned which to me is the cleanest answer:

```
echo -n $str | tail -c 1
```

Note the `-n` is just so the echo doesn't include a newline at the end.

Comment: Not even close to being cleaner than ${str: -1}

Comment: It is cleaner as it doesn't rely on a bash-ism, so it will work with any Posix shell.

Comment: What's the most "bashist"? "${str: -1}" And... What's the most cleaner? "${str: -1}" Bash is the besht! :-)

Comment: For anyone trying to print the last characters on a big file, this did the job for me:

cat user/folder/file.json | tail -c 1

You can replace the 1 with the number of characters you want to print.

Answer (score 23):

Every answer so far implies the word "shell" in the question equates to Bash.

This is how one could do that in a standard Bourne shell:

```
printf "%s" "$str" | tail -c 1
```

Comment: `echo -n` as proposed by user5394399 avoids problems when `$str` contains special format characters.

Comment: The `-n` switch is a bashism. It won't work in standard Bourne shell as dash, etc... Which was the point of my answer.

Comment: Not quite a bashism, but POSIX recognizes it is implementation defined ("If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined").  Your answer could instead be fixed with `printf "%s" "$str" | ...` :-).

Answer (score 7):

another solution using awk script:

last 1 char:

```
echo $str | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'
```

last 5 chars:

```
echo $str | awk '{print substr($0,length-5,5)}'
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked for, but this is the best solution I've found to be used with a file. Most other approaches won't work cat-ing a file to it, as in : 
`cat file | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'`
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Single line:

```
${str:${#str}-1:1}
```

Now:

```
echo "${str:${#str}-1:1}"
```

Comment: Why do you use two pairs of parentheses? Also, since 4.2, you can use negative offsets, as shown in quickshiftin's answer: `echo "${str: -1}"` is enough (mind the space between `:` and `-`).

Comment: Two pairs of parentheses are used for arithmetic operations

Comment: No. Please see [the relevant part of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) where you'll read: _length_ and _offset_ are arithmetic expressions (see [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)); hence you're already in shell arithmetic and don't need any parentheses at all. Besides, if what you said were true, it would be more logical to have an _arithmetic expansion_ with `$((...))`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you are right! I now understand your previous question. Answer updated

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
"${str:$((${#str}-1)):1}"
```

For e.g.:

```
someone@mypc:~$ str="A random string*"; echo "$str"
A random string*
someone@mypc:~$ echo "${str:$((${#str}-1)):1}"
*
someone@mypc:~$ echo "${str:$((${#str}-2)):1}"
g
```

Answer (score 3):

For [portability](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
you can say `"${s#"${s%?}"}"`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
m=bzzzM n=bzzzN
for s in \
    'vv'  'w'   ''    'uu  ' ' uu ' '  uu' / \
    'ab?' 'a?b' '?ab' 'ab??' 'a??b' '??ab' / \
    'cd#' 'c#d' '#cd' 'cd##' 'c##d' '##cd' / \
    'ef%' 'e%f' '%ef' 'ef%%' 'e%%f' '%%ef' / \
    'gh*' 'g*h' '*gh' 'gh**' 'g**h' '**gh' / \
    'ij"' 'i"j' '"ij' "ij'"  "i'j"  "'ij"  / \
    'kl{' 'k{l' '{kl' 'kl{}' 'k{}l' '{}kl' / \
    'mn$' 'm$n' '$mn' 'mn$$' 'm$$n' '$$mn' /
do  case $s in
    (/) printf '\n' ;;
    (*) printf '.%s. ' "${s#"${s%?}"}" ;;
    esac
done
```

Output:

```
.v. .w. .. . . . . .u. 
.?. .b. .b. .?. .b. .b. 
.#. .d. .d. .#. .d. .d. 
.%. .f. .f. .%. .f. .f. 
.*. .h. .h. .*. .h. .h. 
.". .j. .j. .'. .j. .j. 
.{. .l. .l. .}. .l. .l. 
.$. .n. .n. .$. .n. .n.
```

Comment: This is POSIX compatible and short 

Answer (score 1):

```
expr $str : '.*\(.\)'
```

Or

```
echo ${str: -1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a pure POSIX method:

https://github.com/spiralofhope/shell-random/blob/master/live/sh/scripts/string-fetch-last-character.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env  sh

string_fetch_last_character() {
  length_of_string=${#string}
  last_character="$string"
  i=1
  until [ $i -eq "$length_of_string" ]; do
    last_character="${last_character#?}"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done

  printf  '%s'  "$last_character"
}


string_fetch_last_character  "$string"
```

Comment: The previous answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64616928/3573263, is also POSIX, and much shorter.

Answer (score -3):

```
echo $str | cut -c $((${#str}))
```

is a good approach